# RestKit Entity Mapping and Parent Entity Mapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit

I have a Person class (attributes of firstName and lastName) and another entity Worker (attributes of wage and title). In my Core Data model the Person entity is set as the parent of the Worker entity. In my AppDelegate I setup my mapping...

```
RKManagedObjectMapping* personMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Person" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[personMapping mapKeyPath:@"lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];    
[objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:personMapping];

RKManagedObjectMapping* workerMapping = [RKManagedObjectMapping mappingForEntityWithName:@"Worker" inManagedObjectStore:objectManager.objectStore];
[workerMapping mapKeyPath:@"wage" toAttribute:@"wage"];
[workerMapping mapKeyPath:@"title" toAttribute:@"title"];
[objectManager.mappingProvider setMapping:workerMapping forKeyPath:@"workers"];    

RKManagedObjectSeeder* seeder = [RKManagedObjectSeeder objectSeederWithObjectManager:objectManager];
[seeder seedObjectsFromFiles:@"people.json", nil];
```

...in people.json...

```
{
    "workers":
    [
        {
            "firstName":"Rob",
            "lastName":"Johnson"
        },
        {
            "firstName":"John",
            "lastName":"Roberts"
        }
    ]
}
```

...now when I run this no objects are seeded. How to do I express the fact that the Worker class has the same mappings as Person? I could just add them to that mapping but that feels wrong.

Also when registering the Person mappings using...

```
[objectManager.mappingProvider addObjectMapping:personMapping];
```

...I don't use the RKManagedObjectMapping method setMapping:forKeyPath: because we'll never experience just a Person in this application and so we'll never be mapping it. But I still want it registered. for Person's child entities.

Comment: Can you try this: [[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setObjectMapping:personMapping forKeyPath:@"workers"] ? I am new to restkit but as far as i understand it you have to somehow include the "workers:" in your keypath and think this will do this. Why it is called workes but do not return wage and title?

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try! For your question, I was just quickly throwing this together and hadn't yet added those values.

Comment: maybe you can eperiment with this too: [personMapping mapKeyPath:@"workers.firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];

Answer (score 0):

You're not telling the object mapper to do anything with the `firstName` and `lastName` fields. You've only defined mappings for `wage` and `title`. In order for your seeding to work, you need to define mappings for the structure of the JSON as well as your web service and add something like:

```
[workerMapping mapKeyPath:@"workers.firstName" toAttribute:@"firstName"];
[workerMapping mapKeyPath:@"workers.lastName" toAttribute:@"lastName"];
```

Then, when you run your seeding, your worker mapper will know how to map those values from your `people.json` to your new `Worker` objects.